# Running a service periodically from Sync Adapter

Tags: android

My background service is constantly getting killed only in specific devices like Lenovo vibe k5 (Already disabled Background App Management App). I've already tried checking if the service is running using Alarm Manager and GCM Periodic Task service but even these does not work when the app is killed but apps like Facebook and Gmail does get notifications. So I want to implement periodic sync using sync adapter to check if the service is running but couldn't find any proper documentation to get that to work. Can anyone provide me a reference on how to implement this?

Comment: First of all, did you try to return START_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058682/difference-between-start-sticky-and-start-redeliver-intent

Comment: Yes I did. I'm using START_STICKY.

Comment: When the app is killed, even onDestroy() and onTaskRemoved are not called.

Comment: @AmanKaushik see this answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/35654729/4146722

Comment: Also, u can try to use AlarmManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Btw, if that phone has some native energy saver - it can kill your service, u can try to disable it.

Comment: @GoltsevEugene Power saver is already disabled and Alarm Manager is also not working. And it is only happening in specific devices. In Xiaomi devices this problem goes away if the auto start has been turned on in Security but no solution for lenovo so far.

Comment: can you show us your service?

Comment: @AmanKaushik Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @ShyamalParikh Yes but not with SyncAdapter.